# How to preserve informations about original observable on RxJava2

Tags: rx-java2

I have a REST call returning a collection (the original), this collection is filtered but on the subscribe `onSuccess` I what to obtain both the original list and the filtered one.

I don't know how to 'pass' this second element, which operator should I use to obtain this result?

I show a simplified version of my code below

```
    Observable.fromCallable(new Callable<List<Integer>>() {
        @Override public List<Integer> call() throws Exception {
            // dynamic list obtained from REST call
            // for simplicity here I return a list
            return Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4);
        }
    })
            .flatMap(new Function<List<Integer>, ObservableSource<Integer>>() {
                @Override public ObservableSource<Integer> apply(List<Integer> integers) throws Exception {
                    return Observable.fromIterable(integers);
                }
            })
            .filter(new Predicate<Integer>() {
                @Override public boolean test(Integer integer) throws Exception {
                    return integer > 2;
                }
            })
            .toList()
            .subscribe(new SingleObserver<List<Integer>>() {
                @Override public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {}

                @Override public void onSuccess(List<Integer> value) {
                    ///////////////////
                    // here I want both original and filtered list
                    ///////////////////
                }

                @Override public void onError(Throwable e) {}
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is with `ConnectableObservable`. You need to share the emissions of your initial stream. Something like this

```
ConnectableObservable<List<Integer>> connectableObservable
                = Observable.fromCallable(() -> {
                    // dynamic list obtained from REST call
                    // for simplicity here I return a list
                    return Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4);
                }).publish();

        Single.zip(connectableObservable.flatMapIterable(integers -> integers)
                .filter(integer -> integer > 2)
                    .toList(),
                 connectableObservable.elementAtOrError(0),
                 (integers, lists) -> combine(integers, lists))
                .subscribe(o -> {
                    ///////////////////
                    // here you ll have a new object containing both the initial list and the filtered list
                    ///////////////////
                });
        connectableObservable.connect();
```

Comment: It sounds a bit complex to just 'pass' a second parameter, maybe I will do everything inside the callable, but thanks for the important hint